# Replacing a fuel filter on a 1999 Infiniti QX4?

Tags: fuel-filter

I'm a pretty average at best wrench guy just wondering if I'm getting in over my head?

Answer (score 1):

It depends what kind of access you have. On this vehicle, the fuel filter is at the rear, near the fuel tank, above the rear differential. It's held on by a single 10 mm bolt, and the 2 fuel lines are clamped on by 2 screws.

1. Relieve the fuel pressure (on most cars, remove the fuel pump fuse or relay, start the engine and let it run until it shuts off. Then crank it for 4 good seconds.)
2. Loosen the clamps, then yank the rubber hoses off. (If you leave the 10 mm bolt in, you can use both hands to yank on the hose. Given age and mileage, it's probably on there pretty good.)
3. Remove the 10 mm bolt
4. Remove the fuel filter
5. Install the new filter
6. Bolt it down.
7. Hook the hoses back on.
8. Clamp them down
9. Re-pressurise the fuel system (put the fuse or relay back in, cycle the key to on a few times)

You may or may not need to get the back of the vehicle up so you can get underneath it. Floor jack and jackstands, or ramps. Whichever you use, make sure the vehicle is stable and the front wheels are blocked before getting under there.

Here's a video of a guy doing it (I believe he's using a hoist.)
https://youtu.be/prK3mvAOOS8